Uri to File to Font in Jetpack Compose
I know how to use fonts from resourses. But I don't want to load the app with a bunch of fonts. Therefore, it probably possible to use fonts from the local storage using Uri or something else.
How to use the font after receiving the Uri of the file?
After some attempts to get the file and use it as a font, an error appears.
This is where the uri and file received:
// use the standard font if null
val currentFont = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

val fontPath = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
val fontFile = remember { mutableStateOf<File?>(null) }

val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { uri ->
    if (uri != null) {
        fontPath.value = uri.path
        if (fontPath.value != null) {
            if (fontPath.value!!.contains("document/raw:")) {
                fontPath.value = fontPath.value!!.replace("/document/raw:","");
            }
            fontFile.value = File(fontPath.value)
            currentFont.value = "name_in_future"
        }
    }
}

//In UI 
...
RegularButton(title = "Button") { launcher.launch(arrayOf("*/*")) }
...

The UI:
CustomTextField(
                        value = framesText[page.value.toInt() - 1],
                        onValueChange = { framesText[page.value.toInt() - 1] = it },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
                            .border(1.dp, Color.Black),
                        fontSize = project.value.fontSize.sp,
                        // WORK_HERE ->
                        font = if (fontFile.value != null) Font(fontFile.value!!) else Font(R.font.jet_brains_mono),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart
                    )

This is the text field:
@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
   value: String,
   onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
   modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
   fontSize: TextUnit = 20.sp,
   font: Font = Font(R.font.jet_brains_mono),
   contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
   keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions {},
   keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default
) {

   BasicTextField(
       value = value,
       onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) },
       modifier = modifier,
       textStyle = TextStyle(
           fontSize = fontSize,
           lineHeight = fontSize,
           color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
           fontFamily = FontFamily(font)
       ),
       cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
       keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
       keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions
   ) { innerTextField ->
       Box(modifier = Modifier
           .background(
               color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
               shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
           )
           .padding(4.dp)
           .fillMaxHeight(),
           contentAlignment = contentAlignment,
           content = { innerTextField() }
       )
   }
}

And this is the errors:
Error mapping font file /storage/emulated/0/Download/RobotoMono-VariableFont_wght.ttf
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load font

//And the same with "/document/raw:":
Error mapping font file /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/RobotoMono-VariableFont_wght.ttf

